# Is there a word that describes both the boss and the employees?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to create a table with all the people who works in a store. What would be the title of such a table? "Members"? "Workers", "Employees", something else?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also: [workplace.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Try all who work in a store.

Comment: @Kris - I didn't quite understand what is this site and how he could help me...

Comment: "Staff," unless the manager is also the proprietor, in which case it's her choice.

Comment: @Rathony - I need only one word.

Comment: @Rob_Ster - Well, "staff members" sounds good, but is there an equivalent single-word? Thanks.

Comment: Hit the link I provided to the Workplace site. This Q may have already been dealt with there or you could ask now. I'm not sure if this Q belongs on ELU.

Comment: @Sipo - "Members" is nice but superfluous. Look up "staff." It's a perfectly good noun in its own right.

Comment: @Rob_Ster - Thanks! Also, could "staffer" be a good choice for describing a single staff member?

Comment: Personnel, Staff, Workforce etc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about naming things, which is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Organisation....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [Workforce](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/workforce)

> the group of people who work for a particular organization or business

Synonyms include [Personnel](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/personnel), [Staff](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/staff)

Comment: I do want to include the store owner, but he is also a co-worker since he works at the store, so he should be on the list.

Comment: It was by mistake. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A boss is not necessarily an employer. A boss is someone who bosses (directs, manages, supervises,...) others.

If the employer is a corporation or other non-human entity/organization, and **if the boss is also an employee**, then the word is *employee*. This is perhaps the most common case.

If the boss is the employer (a human, such as a business owner) then there is no term I'm aware of - they are all people at XYZ organization.

And IMO, *workforce* refers not to an employer but to those who are employed. This can include bosses, if they too are employees.

Similarly, if the workers are not actually employees - for example, in a volunteer organization. There, bosses and those whom they boss are perhaps all *members* (or associates or volunteers or participants) of the organization.

Comment: What about "Staffer"?

Comment: @Sipo: From WordWebOnline, a [staffer](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=staffer) is an employee, and the [staff](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=staff) members are (1) "Personnel who assist their superior in carrying out an assigned task" or (2) "The body of teachers and administrators at a school." Staff does not usually include employers, unless s?he is also an employee, but any staff or workforce can include bosses at different levels.